# How do I go about creating this relationship in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

When I try `Add-Migration`, I get this error:
`Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Book.Authors' of type 'ICollection<Person>'`

What I am trying to do, each person could be an author, translator or a reviewer of different books. Accordingly, each book can have multiple persons acting on different capacities (i.e., translators, authors, and reviewers.)

I know that many-to-many relationships are supported according to the docs. So, what am I missing?

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string? Subtitle { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person> Authors { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person> Reviewers { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person> Translators { get; set; }
}


public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Book> BooksAuthored { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Book> BooksReviewed { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Book> BooksTranslated { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: NOTE: you *can* create a "PersonBook" table in your database by nesting class "Person" inside class "Book".  But that' would correspond to the C# class "Book.Findings" ... and it's  not really what you want anyway.  You should simply define the classes separately, and relate the tables individually.  Which is precisely what the error message is telling you.  I suspect you might also want individual EF model classes for "BooksReviewed, BooksAuthored, and BooksTranslated".

Answer (score 1):

You need separate linking tables/entities for each relationship.  Try this

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string? Subtitle { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person> Authors { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person> Reviewers { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person> Translators { get; set; }
}


public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Book.Authors))]
    public ICollection<Book> BooksAuthored { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Book.Reviewers))]
    public ICollection<Book> BooksReviewed { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Book.Translators))]
    public ICollection<Book> BooksTranslated { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I mistakenly used the wrong type. I have each in its own class. However, I did not have `[InverseProperty]` attribute. I tried it and I'm getting this error now:
`The [InverseProperty] attribute on property 'Book.Authors' is not valid. The property 'Authors' is not a valid navigation on the related type 'Person'. Ensure that the property exists and is a valid reference or collection navigation.`

Comment: The code in the answer works on EF Core 6 and later.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I had to clean my solution and rebuild it. Can you tell me how to assign a book to an author? Do I have to send the entire Person inside Book to be able to add an author to a book? Ideally, I'd like to add a Person, then be able to add a Book to it. Or if that person doesn't exist while adding a book, create that Person.

Answer (score 0):

When you have several relationships between two tables, you will need to be explicit with EF with how these entities are related. Think of it from the database side of things, how would you store this information?

One option would be to have:

```
Book - Authors (BookId+PersonId) - Person
+
Book - Reviewers (BookId+PersonId) - Person
+
Book - Translators (BookId+PersonId) - Person
```

This would involve 3 joining tables for the 3 distinct relationships. In this case EF would need to be told which table to use for each relationship, but other than that it should work as you expect since EF can work them out by type.

The other option would be to have a single PersonBook table with a discriminator, something like a Relationship column stating the type of relationship being "Author", "Reviewer" or "Translator". In this scenario the mapping would look something more like:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string? Subtitle { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PersonBook> PersonBooks { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<Person> Authors => PersonBooks
        .Where(pb => pb.Relationship == "Author")
        .Select(pb => pb.Person);

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<Person> Reviewers => PersonBooks
        .Where(pb => pb.Relationship == "Reviewer")
        .Select(pb => pb.Person);

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<Person> Translators => PersonBooks
        .Where(pb => pb.Relationship == "Translator")
        .Select(pb => pb.Person);


}

public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PersonBook> PersonBooks { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<Person> BooksIAuthored => PersonBooks
        .Where(pb => pb.Relationship == "Author")
        .Select(pb => pb.Book);

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<Person> BooksIReviewed => PersonBooks
        .Where(pb => pb.Relationship == "Reviewer")
        .Select(pb => pb.Book);

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<Person> BooksITranslated => PersonBooks
        .Where(pb => pb.Relationship == "Translator")
        .Select(pb => pb.Book);
}
```

Where the discriminator could be a string or enumeration to avoid typo errors and save on a bit of storage space. The caveat of the 2nd approach is that the 3 collections rely on the BookPersons being eager or lazy loaded and they cannot be used in Linq query expressions that EF would be converting to SQL.

For instance if you wanted to get all books by a particular author you cannot use:

```
var books = context.Books
    .Where(b => b.Authors.Any(a => a.AuthorId == authorId))
    .ToList();
```

becaause the Authors are an unmapped property derived from BookPersons.. To get the authors you need to go through the BookPersons collection:

```
var books = context.Books
    .Where(b => b.BookPersons.Any(bp => pb.Relationship == "Author" && pb.PersonId == authorId))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: In 2nd approach, how would I go about getting a list of books that were authored by a certain Person? Also, why did you choose to name it PersonBooks and not PersonBook or PersonsBook?

Comment: You can configure the table naming however you like, if EF Code First is left in charge it would likely use PersonBooks or BookPersons. The example  I had at the end of the question shows how to get all books authored by a specific person. (personId) If you exclude the Relationship filter that would get you all books that the given Person was either Author, Reviewer, or Translator.  The first option is "safer", and can accommodate relationship-specific fields (i.e. fields used only for an Author relationship) better than adding null-able fields to a PersonBooks table.